# Permutation of items with repetition and forbidden orderings

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to solve this question

> In a photo there are three families six Greens, four Browns and seven Grays arranged in a row. The Browns have had an argument so no Brown will stand next to another Brown. How many different permutation are permitted?

This is what I tried, I arranged the other families other than the Browns, that is $13$ persons in a row so I have $13!$, - - - - - - - - - - - - - , then I will have $14$ gaps between these places and I need four places four the Browns so I'll will have $C_4^{14}$, then I have $4!$ choices to put the Browns in the gaps so my answer is $$13!\times(C_4^{14})\times4!$$ but its different that the answer in the book and I don't know what went wrong?
The answer in the book is: $150\times10^{14}$
and the answer I am getting is $1.495\times10^{14}$
any Ideas? Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer, $13!{14\choose4}4!$, equals $149597947699200$. The book seems to have rounded the answer to one fewer significant figure than you did, [following edited after Ross's comment] but perhaps inadvertently either a) omitted a decimal point and meant to write $1.50$, or b) meant to express the answer in "engineer's notation" using powers of 10 divisible by 3, but forgot to change the $14$ to a $12.$

Comment: OP and the book disagree by a factor $100$

Comment: Argh. Silly me for only looking at the significant digits... Will add a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine putting a non-Brown on the right of each Brown, putting a new slot to the right of the last (in case a Brown is at the right end).  You now have four pairs with a Brown on the left and ten non-Browns (including one extra for the last slot).  Select the locations for the Brown/nonBrown pairs in $14C4$ ways.  Erase the last non-Brown.  Then order the Browns and the others.  I claim the answer is ${14 \choose 4}4!13!=149,597,947,699,200\approx 1.5 \cdot 10^{14}$, which agrees with you

Comment: ok thanks, so the textbook is wrong ?